# Managing Firebase's concurrent users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a few microservices (AWS Lambda) which when started will authenticate with Firebase, change state in an appropriate manner, and then stop execution.

I have found out tonight though that I must not be cleaning up after myself as I have 100 concurrent users and it's only me doing some testing work (albeit testing authentication).

I've seen references to the `goOffline()` method and possibly could use that but it seems a little hacky. Are there any good examples of how one can ensure that you're closing and/or reusing an existing connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When spinning up server-side processes that use Firebase it's vital that you make sure the process is completed when killed.

If the process is killed, then the connection will get killed as well. But, there's nothing hacky about calling `Firebase.goOffline()`, as it will close the connection.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if there is a one-off process I can go through to clear out all the excess user sessions?

Comment: Oh, one last question. Is `goOffline()` better than `unauth()`?

Comment: Firebase doesn't have control over any rogue processes, you'll need to kill those from your server. And `unauth()` will simply unauthenticate and `goOffline()` will kill the connection. But if you go back online, you will still be authenticated if you did not call `unauth()`.

Comment: Well the processes are already long since gone. I'd have thought this would drop the connections after a reasonable timeout but it's been a few hours and I haven't seen any drop off.

Comment: Actually I may have spoken a little too soon, it appears they are now starting to drop down. I'm at about 50 now but it did take several hours.

Comment: The stats take about 15-30 minutes to reflect the real state. Also when you don't control the server it's hard to tell what's happening to the processes.